# Performance improvement in the query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the below query that does a self join on the Locations table. When I run this query on a million records, it takes more than 2 hours to execute. Would really appreciate if any performance improvement can be done on this query so that execution time be improved.

```
SELECT
    a.Id1, a.Id2, a.LocationStart, a.LocationEnd
FROM
    Locations AS a
JOIN
    Locations AS b
ON
    a.Id1= b.Id1 AND a.Id2 = b.Id2
WHERE
    a.DateTime = (
        SELECT
            MIN(DateTime)
        FROM
            Locations
        WHERE
            Id1 = a.Id1
            AND Id2 = a.Id2)
```

Comment: Huh, but what you are trying actually to solve here? Maybe the problem has different approach than running query on 1e^18 results.

Comment: What for do you need `Locations AS b` ? It is unused

Answer (score 1):

I would observe that your query doesn't really make sense.  I assume it is oversimplified, so I'll include columns from both table references.

I would start by using window functions:

```
SELECT l.Id1, l.Id2, l2.id1, l2.id2, l.LocationStart, l.LocationEnd
FROM (SELECT l.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2 ORDER BY datetime ASC) as seqnum
      FROM Locations l
     ) l JOIN
    Locations l2
    ON l.Id1 = l2.Id1 AND l.Id2 = l2.Id2 AND l.seqnum = 1;
```

This assumes that you are looking for a *unique* value from the first table (that is, there are no date time duplicates).

Next, I would observe that you simply want the first value for the `l1` fields.  Guess what?  You don't need a `join` at all.

```
select first_value(l.id1) over (partition by id1, id2 order by datetime),
       first_value(l.id2) over (partition by id1, id2 order by datetime),
       l.id1,
       l.id2,
       first_value(l.locationstart) over (partition by id1, id2 order by datetime),
       first_value(l.locationend) over (partition by id1, id2 order by datetime)    
from locations l;
```